# Update Column with 2nd Highest Number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Code:**

```
update [MemberBackup].[dbo].[uid3times$]
set rc2tobedeleted =
case when rc1 > rc2 and rc1 > rc3 and rc2 < rc3 then rc2
when  rc2 > rc3 and rc2 > rc1  and rc1 < rc3 then rc1
when rc3 > rc1 and rc3 > rc2  and rc1 < rc2 then rc1 
else 0 end
```

I have 3 columns rc1,rc2,rc3 and the numbers in 3 columns are random I want to update/set the 2nd Highest Number in `rc2tobedeleted`

But my code is coming to else where as I think i have take care of 3 possible condition.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giorgos answer is great, but it can be simplified like this for `Sql server 2012` and above

```
UPDATE [MemberBackup].[dbo].[uid3times$]
SET    rc2tobedeleted = (SELECT rc
                         FROM   (VALUES (rc1),(rc2),(rc3) ) tc (rc)
                         ORDER  BY rc DESC
                         OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH next 1 rows only)
```

for older versions use this

```
UPDATE [MemberBackup].[dbo].[uid3times$]
SET    rc2tobedeleted = (SELECT rc
                         FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY rc DESC) rn,rc
                                 FROM   (VALUES (rc1),(rc2),(rc3) ) tc (rc)) a
                         WHERE  rn = 2)
```

Idea here is, unpivoting the three columns to single column and generating row number on unpivoted rows and updating the record which is having row number as `2`

Another advantage in this approach is even you have more than 3 three column and you want to find the nth record then it is much easier and elegant than clumsy `CASE` statement

Comment: what if their are 4 values instead of 3?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee - Simple add the 4th column to table valued constructor. Like this `(VALUES (rc1),(rc2),(rc3),(rc4))`

Comment: and if i want the 3rd highest then rn = 3 or offset 2 right?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee - Yes.. In first solution it would be `OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH next 1 rows only`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT rc2tobedeleted, t.v AS val
   FROM [MemberBackup].[dbo].[uid3times$]
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT x.v
      FROM (VALUES (rc1), (rc2), (rc3) ) AS x(v)
      ORDER BY x.v DESC 
      OFFSET 1 ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS t
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET rc2tobedeleted = val
```

I think the above query has a much cleaner and easy to understand structure in comparison to the multiple `WHEN` clauses of a `CASE` expression.

The query uses [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) Table Value Constructor in order to build an inline table consisting of the values of fields `rc1, rc2, rc3`. Using the [**`OFFSET FETCH`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) clause, available from SQL Server 2012 onward, we can get the second highest value.

Finally, the `UPDATE` operation is performed using a [**`CTE`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx): the update is propagated from the `CTE` to the underlying rows of the real table stored in the database.

Comment: Very elegant! +1!

Comment: what if their are 4 values instead of 3?